# Does VirtIO storage support discard (fstrim)?

Tags: libvirt, virtio, fstrim

```
$ uname -r
5.0.9-301.fc30.x86_64
$ findmnt /
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/vda3 ext4   rw,relatime,seclabel
$ sudo fstrim -v /
fstrim: /: the discard operation is not supported
```

Same VM, but after switching the disk from VirtIO to SATA:

```
$ findmnt /
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda3 ext4   rw,relatime,seclabel
$ sudo fstrim -v /
/: 5.3 GiB (5699264512 bytes) trimmed
```

The virtual disk is backed by a QCOW2 file.  I am using virt-manager / libvirt.  libvirt-daemon is version 4.7.0-2.fc29.x86_64.  My host is currently running a vanilla kernel build 5.1 (ish), so it's a little bit "customized" at the moment, but I built it starting from a stock Fedora kernel configuration.

Is there a way to enable discard support on VirtIO somehow?  Or does the code just not support it yet?  I don't necessarily require the exact instructions how to enable it, but I am surprised and curious and I would like a solid answer :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently discard wasn't supported on that setting.  However it can work if you change the disk from "VirtIO" to "SCSI", and change the SCSI controller to "VirtIO".  I found a [walkthrough](https://chrisirwin.ca/posts/discard-with-kvm/).  There are several walkthroughs; that was just the first search result.  This new option is called `virtio-scsi`.  The other, older system is called `virtio-block` or `virtio-blk`.

I also found a great thread on the [Ubuntu bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1523246).  It points out that `virtio-blk` starts supporting discard requests in Linux 5.0.  It says this also requires support in QEMU, which was committed on 22 Feb 2019.  Therefore in future versions, I think we will automatically get both VirtIO and discard support.

---

Currently my `virt-manager` does not create `virtio-scsi` disks by default, even when it knows I am installing Fedora 29; it only creates the basic "VirtIO" disks.  I do not know if there is any disadvantage of switching to `virtio-scsi`.

I guess `virtio-scsi` provides the same sort of performance advantage as `virtio-blk`, when compared to emulated SATA.  (I do not see an option to use NVME protocol anywhere in `virt-manager` :-P, with or without VirtIO).

The oVirt website has some [nice propaganda](https://www.ovirt.org/develop/release-management/features/storage/virtio-scsi.html), which mentions

1. some limitations in `virtio-blk`
2. `virtio-scsi` can be used in pass-through mode to a SCSI LUN, and can use various new SCSI command features without needing modifications in `virtio-scsi` .  If you are not specifically using SCSI pass-through, then any new commands will require new support in QEMU, but not in the `virtio-scsi` code.
3. `virtio-scsi` includes support for multiple queues.  (I am not clear whether this is also helpful for efficiency on single-queue hardware, or not).

Comment: You should use virtio-scsi anyway; virtio-blk doesn't have as good performance and AFAIK isn't being well maintained anymore. virt-manager will eventually catch up; they use extremely conservative default settings unfortunately.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I suppose `virtio-scsi` got discard support without needing to add any more specific code for it :-).  I probably won't bother with this issue until my laptop runs out of disk space again :-).  A performance citation would be interesting if you had one.  The references I find say it's mostly about features and flexibility and show the performance is similar in most cases.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: According to RHEL [pdf](https://events19.lfasiallc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Storage-Performance-Tuning-for-FAST-Virtual-Machines_Fam-Zheng.pdf), see page 25. Admit it's from 2008, but still. It says`virtio-blk` has better performance and should be selected when possible. It's my impression it's still very much maintained. They "just" added the trim support a few qemu versions back. Are you still holding on to you  statement, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had to explicitly enable discard in the libvirt domain XML file for it to work:

```
   <devices>
     <disk type='file' device='disk'>
-      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
+      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' discard='unmap'/>
       <source file='...'/>
       <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
       <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
     </disk>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to sourcejedi's answer

To support discard in virtio-blk, you also need to update "machine" in the VM config.

- in pc-q35-3.1, virtio-blk does NOT support discard
- in pc-q35-4.2, it does

In any case, it's best to update VM config to the latest machine. Or just use alias "q35" without specifying the exact version

see

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -machine help | grep q35
```

for example,

```
<type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-7.2'>hvm</type>
```